# Whether genus can be nonnegative?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces

From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886878/how-to-compute-the-euler-characteristic-of-s2-times-s2), I know the Euler characteristic of $S^2
\times S^2$ is $4$, and I know the Euler characteristic is equal to $2-2g$, where $g$ is the genus. So I can get the genus is $-1$, but I thought the genus must be nonnegative ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler characteristic of a closed orientable surface is $2 - 2g$ where $g$ is the genus. The genus is always non-negative.

Note that $S^2\times S^2$ is a closed orientable four-dimensional manifold, not a surface, so the Euler characteristic is not given by $2-2g$.

Comment: Thanks. What is the geometry mean of Euler characteristic ?

Comment: That's a good question. Perhaps you can post it as a separate question.